# Make "Un-ordered list" behave like an "ordered list" with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I need to display numbers which each list item in an un-ordered list. To achieve this, I tried to convert an un-ordered `ul` list tag into an ordered `ol` list tag (see my script below). I need to do this because I want each `li` tag to display its order number next to it.

Here is the script that I tried which [I found on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNQxwN):

```
var ul = document.getElementsByClassName("productGrid")[0]
var ol = document.createElement("ol");

var li = ul.querySelectorAll('li');
for(var i=0;i<li.length;i++) {
  ol.appendChild(li[i]);
}

setTimeout(function() {
  ul.parentNode.replaceChild(ol,ul);
},1000);
```

This works but as expected it ruined the "styles" set to that `ul` tag. So instead of turning it into an actual `ol` tag, I need to keep it as a `ul` and display numbers some other way.

How can I use JavaScript to find out how many `li`'s are inside the `ul` tag and then display the appropriate number within the `li` tag (via something like a `span` tag)

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: `ol1` is not a tag name I've ever heard of? Did you mean `ol`? If `ol`, that will select an *existing ordered list*, not an existing *unordered list*

Comment: *“I need to do this because I want each li tag to display its order number next to it.”* You mean like what happens when you apply the CSS `list-style: decimal`?

Comment: I just pasted in the wrong snippet. i fixed it..

Comment: list-style: decimal could work but how do i style the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered a pure-CSS based approach instead?

You could achieve a similar counting effect on an unordered-list without the need for JavaScript via the `:before` pseudo-element, and the [`counter-reset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset) and [`counter-increment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment) CSS properties.

Here's a snippet to demonstrate this technique in action:

```css
.number-list {
  /* Init your custom counter for children */
  counter-reset: number-list-counter;

  /* Hide point list style */
  list-style:none; 
}

.number-list li {
  position:relative;
}

.number-list li:before {
 /* 
  Set content of pseduo element by parent counter
  and increment the counter 
  */
  content: counter(number-list-counter);
  counter-increment: number-list-counter;
  
  /* Offset position of counter pseduo elements */
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-2rem;

  /* Apply some styling to the numbering */
  color: red;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<ul class="number-list">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Orange</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
<ul>
```